# Prove the following expression by changing order of integration

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral, order-of-integration

To prove using change of order of integration :
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)\arcsin(\sin(x)\sin(y))\,dx\, dy=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

**Progress so far**:
Let $\sin x \sin y=\sin z$, therefore $\sin x \cos y .dy= \cos z .dz$
When $x=\pi/2$ then $\sin y= \sin z$ $\implies y=z$
and  when $x=0$ then $\sin z=0 \implies z=0$

Therefore I can write the integral as :
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin x .dx\int_0^z\sin^{-1}(\sin z).\frac{\cos z . dz}{\sin x . \cos y}$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}dx\int_0^z\frac{z. \cos z.dz}{\cos y}$$

But how do I proceed from here? Please guide

Comment: you have dx dy then z ????? You cant have three variables...it must be 2 or 1 not three

Comment: @Isham I converted $dy$ to $dz$ , so basically i still have 2 vars

Comment: no you have in the final line cos(y) with dx and dz  it makes three not two

Comment: $$\sin z=\sin x\sin y\Rightarrow \cos z\ dz=\sin x\cos y\ dy+\sin y\cos x\ dx$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I honestly do not get your substitutions at all.

Using complete elliptic integrals (according to Mathematica's notation, their arguments stand for the elliptic modulus) and Fubini's Theorem we have

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\iint_{(0,\pi/2)^2}\sin(x)\arcsin(\sin(x)\sin(y))\,dx\,dy &=& \iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{x\arcsin(xy)}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}\,dx\,dy\\&=&\iiint_{(0,1)^3}\frac{x^2 y}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)(1-x^2 y^2 z^2)}}\,dx\,dy\,dz\\&=&\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{K(y^2 z^2)-E(y^2 z^2)}{z^2 y\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dy\,dz\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{E(y^2)-(1-y^2)K(y^2)}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dy\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{E(u)-(1-u)K(u)}{2u\sqrt{1-u}}\,du\end{eqnarray*}$$
and we may exploit the Taylor series of $K(u)$ and $E(u)$ to get that the last integral equals
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2}{16^n}\left[\frac{1}{1-2n}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{n-1}}{\sqrt{1-u}}\,du-\int_{0}^{1}u^{n-1}\sqrt{1-u}\,du\right] $$
which by Euler's Beta function simplifies to:
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n(2n+1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}-1\right]\,dz=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{4}(\pi-2)}.$$

An alternative and pretty efficient way for dealing with integrals involving $E(u)$ or $K(u)$ is to [exploit Fourier-Legendre series expansions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03221).

Answer (score 0):

> > **In general, we have the following result:
> > $$\iint_{[0,\frac\pi2]^2}f(\sin x\sin y)\sin y\ \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
> > =\frac\pi2\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$
> > where $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.**

**Proof:**
Consider surface
$$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x,y,z\geq0\},$$
which can be described as
$$x=\sin\varphi\cos\theta,\quad y=\sin\varphi\sin\theta,
\quad z=\cos\theta,\quad
(\theta,\varphi)\in[0,\pi/2]^2.$$
Then $\mathrm{d}S=\sin\varphi\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\varphi$, and
\begin{align*}
I
&=\iint_{[0,\frac\pi2]^2}f(\sin\varphi\sin\theta)\sin\varphi\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&=\iint_Sf(y)\mathrm{d} S\\
&=\iint_Sf(z)\mathrm{d}S\\
&=\iint_{[0,\frac\pi2]^2}f(\cos\varphi)\sin\varphi\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&=\frac\pi2\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Take $f(x)=\arcsin x$, we get
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(x) \, \sin^{-1}(\sin(x) \, \sin(y)) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y=\frac\pi2\int_0^1\arcsin x\mathrm{d}x
=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}.$$